# The meaning of "the heathen horde melted from before them."

Tags: meaning

> The singing arrows fled so swift and thick that they darkened the air,
>   **the heathen horde melted from before them.**

This is from "[Bowman](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Bowm849.shtml)" by Author Macken.

I don't understand the meaning of the sentence below.

the heathen horde melted from before them.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: heathen horde = band of heathens, melted = vanished/ran away, from before them = from in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

"Heathen" means barbarian or non-christian.  It is often used negatively to mean uncivilised or wild people (so don't go calling your Buddhist friend a heathen!), so a heathen horde is an army of barbarians.

The rest is a metaphor.  When something melt it loses its structure and disappears ("The snowman had melted leaving only a hat and a carrot on the ground")  Similarly, the army lost its structure and went away.

It is clear that Macken is fond of metaphor. That one sentence has (at least) three: "singing arrows" (arrows don't really sing), "darkened the air" (the air didn't change colour) and "melted" (nothing was molten).

Comment: James, thank you so much for your detailed answer!